# Unity Registration by convention - MatchingInterface property not found

Tags: c#, unity-container

I would like to use the registration by convention feature from unity in a project. Therefore, I followed this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec24) from Microsoft. Unfortunately, I am not able to find the property `MatchingInterface` from the class `WithMappings`. I would like to use this property since I have multiple classes and interface like `IFoo` and `Foo`.

Does someone solved this problem or have a idea?

My unity container version is 5.2.1., freshly installed from NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that implementation of the method `RegisterTypes()` changed. The second parameter requires a function delegate which returns the types which are matching the some condition. In my case `container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath(), (c) => WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface(c));` solved the problem.